I need to find the average number, I have this code,
for some reason that I don't understand, the code doesn't output anything
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

if a > b and a > c and b > c:
    print(b)
if a > c and a > b and c > b:
    print(c)
if b > a and b > c and a > c:
    print(a)


If the user inputs for example a = 1,  b = 2, c = 3 then which of those conditions is true?

Average or median? See here.

I think he just want the number in "the middle" out of specifically 3 inputs, nothing more

You are missing cases. For example, for the example that outputs b, that only works when a > b > c but it doesn't have the flipped case of c > b > a. It also fails when any of the numbers are equal.
You can either completely get around this by just sorting the numbers and then grab the 2nd element. If you still want to use if/else logic for learning purposes, you can benefit from using two-sided inequalities and keep in mind that there are two possible conditions for each end result:
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

# Method 1: Sort and grab middle
print(sorted([a, b, c])[1])

# Method 2: two-sided inequalities
if b <= a <= c or c <= a <= b:
    print(a)
elif a <= b <= c or c <= b <= a:
    print(b)
elif a <= c <= b or b <= c <= a:
    print(c)

